# É possível listar as branchs ordenando-as pelo commit mais recente?

Tags: git

Exemplificando, uso o seguinte comando para listar as *branchs* com as correspondentes saídas no terminal:

```
$ git branch -v
```

---

```
  develop                e946381 [behind 5] Merge branch 'develop' of ...
* feat/manga_com_leite   56b5aa0 refactor: improve ...
  master                 536b4af Merge pull request #149 ...
```

Ou `git branch -v -r` para listar também as *branchs* remotas:

```
$ git branch -v -r
```

---

```
origin/HEAD                                -> origin/master
origin/develop                             b80a76c Merge pull request #148 ...
origin/feat/pastel_queijo                  0b1524b fix cache ...
origin/feat/acai_com_farinha               73984ef chore: update version to ...
.
.
.
# demais branchs
```

Existe alguma forma de ordenar as *branchs* seguindo como critério o *commit* mais recente?

Por exemplo, ao usar `git branch -v`, a listagem seria:

1. *branch* `feat/manga_com_leite` deveria ser a primeira (pois ela detém o *commit* mais recente);
2. a `master` deveria ser a segunda;
3. e por fim a `develop` onde seu último *commit* é o mais velho.

Comment: Eu não vou escrever uma resposta no momento porque estou quase indo dormir. No caso você pode usar a [opção `--sort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---sortltkeygt) para classificar os branchs segundo a data do commit  `git branch -v --sort=committerdate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o @AugustoVasques já comentou, o comando `git branch` tem a opção `--sort` que pode listar as branches por alguma ordem.

Para documentar melhor, o `--sort` já era uma opção que pode ser usada com o comando [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref), por exemplo:

`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate`
ou para listar só as branches locais:
`git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/`

E também pode ser usando com o comando [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch), assim:
`git branch --sort=-committerdate`

As opções de sorting são:
`objectsize`, `authordate`, `committerdate`, `creatordate`, `taggerdate` (mais informações aqui: [git-for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))

E para inverter a ordem basta adicionar um `-` antes, por exemplo:

`--sort=committerdate` ordem crescente de commits
`--sort=-committerdate` ordem decrescente de commits

Aqui um exemplo do retorno, mudando a ordem:

```
$ git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads/
6a6009cda9c5ce62416227af51b5cdb74fe20685 commit refs/heads/
e4a3cf05427d377862df894030abe1f8db489e46 commit refs/heads/
aabb99420d8c87c135d24a226e302878515de841 commit refs/heads/
363b69c8b800ebcac697511150044bff0ce7ceea commit refs/heads/
c5e50f59e11358e2cd13df574407c1b880f8dfa0 commit refs/heads/
41ebbb51fe88983754c632e4c481314cb60dc46f commit refs/heads/
2c01f28ed4b071f7746015120bde945f5b05caeb commit refs/heads/
fdea9c3ce558332b1c93d26cf51ae08de17a35a1 commit refs/heads/

$ git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/
fdea9c3ce558332b1c93d26cf51ae08de17a35a1 commit refs/heads/
2c01f28ed4b071f7746015120bde945f5b05caeb commit refs/heads/
41ebbb51fe88983754c632e4c481314cb60dc46f commit refs/heads/
c5e50f59e11358e2cd13df574407c1b880f8dfa0 commit refs/heads/
363b69c8b800ebcac697511150044bff0ce7ceea commit refs/heads/
aabb99420d8c87c135d24a226e302878515de841 commit refs/heads/
e4a3cf05427d377862df894030abe1f8db489e46 commit refs/heads/
6a6009cda9c5ce62416227af51b5cdb74fe20685 commit refs/heads/
```

É possível notar a inversão do resultado, permitindo usar os critérios em ordem crescente/decrescente